# How to set optionals that are nil to an empty string?

Tags: swift, swift2, option-type

Right now I use the above code to set an optional to an empty string if it's nil and to unwrap it if it has a value. This is only three lines of code but this is a very common operation for me so I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to do this?

```
var notesUnwrapped:String = ""
    if(calendarEvent.notes != nil){
        notesUnwrapped = calendarEvent.notes!
    }
```

Comment: Use `if let`. Explained here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330

Comment: You should really read the language guide.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use nil coalescing operator `??`

```
var notesUnwrapped: String = calendarEvent.notes ?? ""
```

[Swift Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html)

> The nil coalescing operator (a ?? b) unwraps an optional a if it
>   contains a value, or returns a default value b if a is nil. The
>   expression a is always of an optional type. The expression b must
>   match the type that is stored inside a.